# No timers to be deleted for id: xxx

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

Using EJB timers in a singleton session bean in GlassFish 4.1/Java EE 7 as follows.

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
@Startup
public class BackgroundJobManager {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        // Do something.
    }

    @Schedule(hour = "*/1", minute = "0", second = "0", persistent = false)
    public void doHourlyJob() {
        // Do something hourly.
    }

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*/1", second = "0", persistent = false)
    private void doOnEveryMinute() {
        // Do something on every minute.
    }
}
```

Although the log level is `INFO`, the following somewhat wonky caveats appear on the server terminal upon (re)deploying the application.

```
Info:   No timers to be deleted for id: 94427432094072832
Info:   No timers to be deleted for id: 94427432094072832
```

What does it mean? Is it avoidable or the container attempts to warn against something seriously (is there any fix in this case)?

---

The server also logs the following lines on startup.

```
Info:   Portable JNDI names for EJB TimerBean: [java:global/ejb-timer-service-app/TimerBean, java:global/ejb-timer-service-app/TimerBean!org.glassfish.ejb.persistent.timer.TimerLocal]
Info:   Loading application [ejb-timer-service-app] at [/ejb-timer-service-app]
Info:   ejb.timer_service_started
Info:   ==> Restoring Timers ... 
Info:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070
Info:   /file:/C:/Program Files/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/ejb-timer-service-app/WEB-INF/classes/___EJB__Timer__App login successful
Info:   There are no EJB Timers owned by this server
Info:   <== ... Timers Restored.
```

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with GF, but my educated guess would be that GF couldn't find any persistent timers (because you have `persistent=false`) and thus GF didn't find to need to take any action on the timers after (re)start. If they were persistent as in `persistent=true`, then any missing schedules between the last shutdown and the current startup would be immediately executed during startup. Those messages are purely informal, although I must agree that the sentence "No timers to be deleted" is really vague.

Comment: I guessed the same thing about those logs.

Comment: To exclude one and other, just test with `persistent=true` :)

Comment: Setting `persistent` to `true` results in changing one log message `Info:   [2] timers deleted for id: 94480044534005760` another however, remains unchanged `Info:   No timers to be deleted for id: 94480044534005760`. (The server makes an entry for each persistent timer into a database table named `EJB__TIMER__TBL` in MySQL upon shutdown or (re)deploy, when `persistent` is set to `true`. `94480044534005760` is stored in the `APPLICATIONID` column in `EJB__TIMER__TBL` in MySQL. I have configured in the server to use my own JDBC data-source for EJB Timer Service).

Answer (score 0):

This was a quirk in the target IDE, NetBeans (yes, not the container GlassFish itself) and was only reproducible, when the option "Preserve Sessions Across Redeployment" was turned off on the IDE which had to be done prior to NetBeans 8.1.

[image]

(Right click on the server and choose the "property" option from the submenu appeared to open the above frame).

Turning this option on was not possible prior to NetBeans 8.1. Doing so throws an [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33495343/1391249). Thus, sessions are not maintained across subsequent redeployments. Hence, those messages appear.

This no longer exists in NetBeans 8.1. Redeploying an application issues the following safe messages now.

```
Info:   keepstate options resolved to true, saving appId 95015048510636032 for application Project.
Info:   keepstate options resolved to true, saving appId 95015048510636032 for application Project.
Finer:   initialize identitymaps
Info:   Timers will not be destroyed since keepstate is true for application Project
Info:   Timers will not be destroyed since keepstate is true for application Project
```

Persistent timers are thus active during redeployments. They are not destroyed, when an application is redeployed as they should not be.