# NPE at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate$SerializableLocalObjectDelegate.createObject after adding filter

Tags: jakarta-ee, serialization, glassfish, servlet-filters

I've searched a lot and none what I've found solved my problem.
I'm doing a login authentication and trying to use the doFilter method to filter my request. The init function is called, but the doFilter method is not.

This is where I set the "user" attribute in the session. This piece of code is in my Login bean

```
if(LoginValidator.validLogin(usuario, password))
{
     System.out.println("logging " + context.toString());
     context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", usuario);

     return "public/home";
}
```

this is the NoCacheFilter class

```
package Validators;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.application.ResourceHandler;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/public/*")
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter{
private static final String AJAX_REDIRECT_XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
    + "<partial-response><redirect url=\"%s\"></redirect></partial-response>";

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}
@Override
public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("doFilter");

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/index.xhtml";

    boolean loggedIn = (session != null) && (session.getAttribute("user") != null);
    boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL);
    boolean resourceRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER + "/");
    boolean ajaxRequest = "partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader("Faces-Request"));

    if (loggedIn || loginRequest || resourceRequest) {
        if (!resourceRequest) { // Prevent browser from caching restricted resources. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4194207/157882
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response); // So, just continue request.
    }
    else if (ajaxRequest) {
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().printf(AJAX_REDIRECT_XML, loginURL); // So, return special XML response instructing JSF ajax to send a redirect.
    }
    else {
        response.sendRedirect(loginURL); // So, just perform standard synchronous redirect.
    }
}
}
```

This is the log on my server

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate$SerializableLocalObjectDelegate.createObject(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:158)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.GlassFishObjectInputStream.resolveObject(GlassFishObjectInputStream.java:95)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.checkResolve(ObjectInputStream.java:1399)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readRemainingObject(StandardSession.java:2079)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1987)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.deserialize(StandardSession.java:1274)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.readSessions(StandardManager.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadSessions(WebModule.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2288)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:131)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Grave:   IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.IOException
java.io.IOException
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.GlassFishObjectInputStream.resolveObject(GlassFishObjectInputStream.java:112)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.checkResolve(ObjectInputStream.java:1399)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readRemainingObject(StandardSession.java:2079)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1987)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.deserialize(StandardSession.java:1274)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.readSessions(StandardManager.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadSessions(WebModule.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2288)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:131)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate$SerializableLocalObjectDelegate.createObject(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:158)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.GlassFishObjectInputStream.resolveObject(GlassFishObjectInputStream.java:95)
... 81 more

Advertência:   Unable to restore sessions for web module [/SINTS_MA] from previous deployment
java.io.IOException
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.GlassFishObjectInputStream.resolveObject(GlassFishObjectInputStream.java:112)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.checkResolve(ObjectInputStream.java:1399)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readRemainingObject(StandardSession.java:2079)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1987)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.deserialize(StandardSession.java:1274)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.readSessions(StandardManager.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadSessions(WebModule.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2288)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:131)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate$SerializableLocalObjectDelegate.createObject(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:158)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.GlassFishObjectInputStream.resolveObject(GlassFishObjectInputStream.java:95)
... 81 more
```

It might be old question, but I cant find a solution.
I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Tell me, what is line 158 in your code? That is the key

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495343/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-com-sun-ejb-containers-ejblocalobjectinvocatio

Comment: @ShreyansSheth: Really? Or are you being sarcastic?

Comment: no! It says `NullPointerException`. If I have the code than maybe I can debug it. The most probable reason is that you have not instantiated the object

Comment: the line 158 in my Login bean is the signature of the Logout method. In there I call the preparenewLogin, which invalidates the session.

Comment: private String prepareNewLogin()
    {
             FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "/index";
    }

Comment: @Shreyans: Are you new to Java? Have you read the class and method name of that line? That line is clearly not OP's own code. It's GlassFish internal code. Have you read the link OP posted after your comment? Someone else's having the same problem and after all it turns out to be a Netbeans+GlassFish combo specific problem which was for at least two people solved after upgrading Netbeans.

Comment: No i'm not *new* to JAVA. I'm not acquainted with technologies such as GlassFish. My knowledge is based upon Core JAVA, e.i JavaSE. And a normal `NullPointerException` is often solved by debugging the way I mentioned (people often forget to initialize objects). Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Shreyans: it's not a bug in OP's own code. It's a bug in GlassFish server. OP surely isn't a developer of GlassFish server.